# Creating a Table with Rounded Corners

Tags: css, css-tables, rounded-corners

I'm interested in creating a table with rounded corners without using images.

How can this be accomplished?

My idea was that I could wrap the table with a div and to set the rounded corners to the div.
By taking a glance at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VHQsF/) you can see that the tables border overwrites the border of the div. Is there a style which prevents from the overwriting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why dont you just take the border of the table out?

Answer (score 2):

The trick to this working is, as [@Luis implies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6036689/using-rounded-corners-for-tables/6036831#6036831), to take the border off the `table` and apply it to the wrapping `div`, applying the `border-radius` to *that* element.

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/VHQsF/4/).

Answer (score 1):

You can look into PIE CSS3 for IE6/7/8 and then CSS3 effects for Chrome/FF/Opera (http://css3pie.com/)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the table border you could set `border:none` on the table element.  If you still want the table border, you can set a `padding:10px` on the div.